# Dataframe: Keep unique values in a list for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Ville   match
Paris   Talborjt,Talborjt,Ville Nouvelle
Rome    Hay Najah,Hay Najah,Najah
```

I would like to keep the unique values per row of the column match. The desired output is as follows:

```
Ville   match                               contains
Paris   Talborjt,Talborjt,Ville Nouvelle    Talborjt,Ville Nouvelle
Rome    Hay Najah,Hay Najah,Najah           Hay Najah, Najah
```

I have tried the following but did not manage to get the desired output.

```
all_quartiers['contains']=all_quartiers['match'].apply(set).apply(list)

all_quartiers['contains']=all_quartiers['match'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))

all_quartiers['contains']=all_quartiers.explode('match')['match'].unique()
```

Comment: Is your original data strings and not lists?

Comment: Try: `df['contains'] = [list(set(x.split(','))) for x in df['match']]`

Comment: It works fine. Thank you very much. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this solution works for you

```
# Ville   match
# Paris   Talborjt,Talborjt,Ville Nouvelle
# Rome    Hay Najah,Hay Najah,Najah
# import pandas library
import pandas as pd
# Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    {'Ville': 'Paris', 'match': 'Talborjt,Talborjt,Ville Nouvelle'}, 
    {'Ville': 'Rome', 'match': 'Hay Najah,Hay Najah,Najah'}
])
def return_unique(col):
    # 1. it split the string ',' return a list [Talborjt,Talborjt,Ville Nouvelle]
    # 2. convert into set to get unique {Talborjt,Ville Nouvelle}
    # 3. join the set data to with ',' so we get Talborjt,Ville Nouvelle
    return ','.join(set(col.split(','))) 
df['contains'] = df.apply(lambda x: return_unique(x['match']), axis=1)
df
```

[image]